# Can the preposition "in" be used instead of "for" in the following sentence?

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

English grammar books say that when you express a period of time in present perfect, the prepostions such as "for" or "since" should be used.

Example sentences:

> I have lived here for 20 years.
>
> I want to do something I haven't done for years.
>
> I have studied French for three years.

Can I use "in" instead of "for" in these sentences? Are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 3):

**In** can be used instead of **for** only in the second example. The other sentences can have only **for** to be correct.

Edit upon comment: **In** can be used to show the same thing after *first, last,* etc as in:

*It's the first email I've had in ten days*.

And as it's been pointed out, when the sentence is negative, **in** and **for** are interchangeable.

Comment: However, the negatives may be OK: *I haven't lived here in 20 years* ... *I haven't studied French in 3 years.* ... Probably "for" is still better, but "in" is OK.  The reason the second is OK is that it is negative.  *I want to do something I have done in years* is not OK.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this is?

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: Look at the edits in my answer. I looked the information up when I saw GEdgar's comment. It's listed in the uses of the preposition "in".

Answer (score 0):

Here are some thoughts on the topic from a screenplay perspective.

As is pointed out in the comments,

If one uses "for" in temporal context, the use of for is necessary when referring to a positive span of time. As in:

> I smoked for five years.

If one uses for in a negative temporal context:

> I have not touched a cigarette for five years.

it seems to carry a slight tinge of continuation of the state, compare this to

> I have not touched a cigarette in five years.

which seems to bring that state to current close. That is to say, the in implies a closure of the period.

if i was to write a dialogue in a screenplay for two situations:

someone who is saying no to a cigarette i would use the first.

someone who is accepting a cigarette (possibly in a nervous situation and is talking to themselves) i would use the second.

### Addendum

Compare the following remarks from one person to another in a house:

> I haven't been here for a long time.

vs.

> I haven't been here in a long time.

The former implies time period that is continuing (starting from arrival) whereas the latter refers to the state that ended when the subject arrived at the house.